# Regex select 2 elements in table

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

How would I only select the value "CLARO" using regex on this table?

And how would I only select the value "AMBA" on this same table?

```
<div style=" height:40px;"></div>                 
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
            <tr> 
                <td width="120" class="estilotd">   LÃ­nea </td>
                <td width="250" class="estilotd">   Operador </td>
                <td width="150" class="estilotd">   Localidad</td>
                <td width="150" class="estilotd">   Servicio</td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td class="estilotd2">1157670327 </td>
                <td class="estilotd2"> CLARO </td>
                <td class="estilotd2"> AMBA </td>
                <td class="estilotd2"> TELEFONIA MOVIL </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
        <div style="width:665px; height:30px; margin:80px 0 0 70px;">
            <div style="float:left">
            <form action="detectar_empresa_celular.php" target="_self">
                <input type="submit" class="boton" value="â Realizar otra bÃºsqueda">
            </form>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right">
            <form action="titular_de_numero_celular.php" target="_self">
                <input type="submit" class="boton" value="Solicitar Titular de Celular âº">
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values (i.e. you'll always want to find CLARO and AMBA) it is pretty straight forward:

in javascript:

```
var claro =/<td class="estilotd2">( CLARO )(?=<\/td>)/;
var amba = /<td class="estilotd2">( AMBA )(?=<\/td>)/;
```

if you are not in javascript it gets easier because we can use negative lookbehinds:

```
(?<=<td class="estilotd2">)( CLARO )(?=<\/td>)
```

or

If you want to capture more generically you can do something like this:

javascript:

```
var all = /<td class="estilotd2">([^&]*?)(?=<\/td>)/g;
var matches;
while (matches = all.exec(str)) {
   console.log(matches[1]);
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xn4wozf/)

non-javascript:

```
   (?<=<td class="estilotd2">)(.*?)(?=<\/td>)
```

finally...if you are working in the browser, it seems like it might be easier to use selectors to find the values in that tables.  For example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('estilotd');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    console.log(elements[i].innerText);
};
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0Lc08zy/)